# Safety instructions

Tags: verbs

I have answered a safety instruction question today, but the English was funny. It's just a gut feeling, but IMHO the verbs are totally off. What are the correct verbs here? (emphasis mine)

> You recognize a burning trash can in the canteen. What do you have to do?
>
> [_] I immediately **solve** the fire alarm or warn my colleagues
>
> [_] I open all the doord and windows so that the smoke can **deduct**
>
> [_] I'll get the next fire extinguisher and quickly **delete** the fire

I'd use

- ... trigger the fire alarm
- ... smoke can escape
- ... put out the fire (to not use extinguish again)

Comment: I prefer your choice of verbs. Those in the block quote are not idiomatic in BrE, AmE, AusE or even Asian English or Indian English, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 2):

Your verbs are much better.

There is no dictionary definition that makes solve fit in there with regards to a fire alarm.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solve

None of those meanings fits.